Why does Channel<T> work but BlockingCollection<T> not?
As part of a much larger solution, I have a solution for the producer-consumer pattern in .NET. It uses a System.Threading.Channels.Channel for receiving messages from a WebSocket and allowing it to be processed as the messages arrive.
using System.Threading.Channels;

/// <summary>
/// A class that asynchronously dispatches items in a first-in-first-out manner,
/// using a separate thread for dispatching the items.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of items to be dispatched.</typeparam>
public class Dispatcher<T>
{
    private readonly Channel<T> queue = Channel.CreateUnbounded<T>(new UnboundedChannelOptions()
    {
        SingleReader = true,
        SingleWriter = true,
    });

    private readonly Task monitorTask;
    private bool isDispatching;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Dispatcher{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Dispatcher()
    {
        this.monitorTask = Task.Run(async () => await this.MonitorQueue().ConfigureAwait(false));
        this.isDispatching = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when an item is dispatched.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ItemDispatchedEventArgs<T>>? ItemDispatched;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the dispatcher is currently dispatching items.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsDispatching => this.isDispatching;

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to add an item to the queue to be dispatched.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="itemToDispatch">The item to be dispatched.</param>
    /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if the item was queued for dispatching; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.</returns>
    public bool TryDispatch(T itemToDispatch)
    {
        return this.queue.Writer.TryWrite(itemToDispatch);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shuts down the dispatcher.
    /// </summary>
    public void StopDispatching()
    {
        if (this.isDispatching)
        {
            // Attempt to wait for the channel to empty before marking the
            // writer as complete and waiting for the monitor task to end.
            while (this.queue.Reader.TryPeek(out _))
            {
                // N.B. We are doing an explicit .Wait() call here to avoid
                // having this become an async method. Since all we are doing
                // is waiting for the reader to become empty, this should be
                // an acceptable use of a synchronizing API on a typically
                // async structure. If this becomes an issue on shutdown
                // of the Dispatcher, we can add a configurable shutdown timeout.
                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)).Wait();
            }

            this.queue.Writer.Complete();
            this.monitorTask.Wait();
            this.isDispatching = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the ItemDispatched event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The object raising the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The EventArgs containing information about the event.</param>
    protected virtual void OnItemDispatched(object? sender, ItemDispatchedEventArgs<T> e)
    {
        if (this.ItemDispatched is not null)
        {
            this.ItemDispatched(this, e);
        }
    }

    private async Task MonitorQueue()
    {
        while (await this.queue.Reader.WaitToReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            this.DispatchPendingItems();
        }
    }

    private void DispatchPendingItems()
    {
        while (this.queue.Reader.TryRead(out T? item))
        {
            this.OnItemDispatched(this, new ItemDispatchedEventArgs<T>(item));
        }
   }
}

This works remarkably well, but suppose I wanted to replace this implementation with one based on System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection. My initial pass at such an implementation looks like this:
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

/// <summary>
/// A class that asynchronously dispatches items in a first-in-first-out manner,
/// using a separate thread for dispatching the items.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of items to be dispatched.</typeparam>
public class Dispatcher<T>
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> items = new();
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource monitorCancellationTokenSource = new();
    private readonly Task monitorTask;
    private bool isDispatching;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Dispatcher{T}"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public Dispatcher()
    {
        this.monitorTask = Task.Run(() => this.MonitorQueue());
        this.isDispatching = true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when an item is dispatched.
    /// </summary>
    public event EventHandler<ItemDispatchedEventArgs<T>>? ItemDispatched;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the dispatcher is currently dispatching items.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsDispatching => this.isDispatching;

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to add an item to the queue to be dispatched.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="itemToDispatch">The item to be dispatched.</param>
    /// <returns><see langword="true"/> if the item was queued for dispatching; otherwise, <see langword="false"/>.</returns>
    public bool TryDispatch(T itemToDispatch)
    {
        if (this.items.IsAddingCompleted)
        {
            return false;
        }

        this.items.Add(itemToDispatch);
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shuts down the dispatcher.
    /// </summary>
    public void StopDispatching()
    {
        if (this.isDispatching)
        {
            // Attempt to wait for the channel to empty before marking the
            // writer as complete and waiting for the monitor task to end.
            while (this.items.Count > 0)
            {
                // N.B. We are doing an explicit .Wait() call here to avoid
                // having this become an async method. Since all we are doing
                // is waiting for the reader to become empty, this should be
                // an acceptable use of a synchronizing API on a typically
                // async structure. If this becomes an issue on shutdown
                // of the Dispatcher, we can add a configurable shutdown timeout.
                Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10)).Wait();
            }

            this.items.CompleteAdding();
            this.monitorCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            this.monitorTask.Wait();
            this.isDispatching = false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the ItemDispatched event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The object raising the event.</param>
    /// <param name="e">The EventArgs containing information about the event.</param>
    protected virtual void OnItemDispatched(object? sender, ItemDispatchedEventArgs<T> e)
    {
        if (this.ItemDispatched is not null)
        {
            this.ItemDispatched(this, e);
        }
    }

    private void MonitorQueue()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (T itemToDispatch in this.items.GetConsumingEnumerable(this.monitorCancellationTokenSource.Token))
            {
                this.OnItemDispatched(this, new ItemDispatchedEventArgs<T>(itemToDispatch));
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }
    }
}

Now to the root of my question. In my unit tests for the larger project, I have a large body of tests that do the equivalent of:
[Test]
public void TestSomething
{
    // Unit tests don't actually create an independent Dispatcher
    // instance, but does so in context of other objects with
    // proper event handlers hooked up.
    Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher<string>();
    dispatcher.OnItemDispatched += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.DispatchedItem);

    // Do some actions to get items dispatched
    // N.B., tests never explicitly call dispatcher.StopDispatching().
}

When I use the Channel-based implementation, I can run many, many unit tests consecutively. I've not yet encountered a limit to what I can do. When I use the BlockingCollection-based implementation, I can only run a certain number of unit tests before things start going awry. I get items not being consumed by the consumer (not being dispatched). Here's the question: Why?
I have my suspicions on why this would be the case, but I'd love to get some wisdom from other, more knowledgeable people than I. If one of my implementations is incorrect, I'd like to know how to correct it. If it's down to the internals of the .NET classes, I'd like to know that too. Yes, I'm aware that I should clean up the usage in the tests to dispose of the objects properly, but that is orthogonal to the question I'm asking: Why does it work in one case and not the other?

The fact that BlockingCollection works a first few times and then starts to behave weird does smell like a IDisposable issue...

@Dialecticus It kinda does to me too, but, again, the operative question is: Why? Why doesn't Channel<T> suffer from the same problem as BlockingCollection<T>?

Channel is asynchronous, BlockingCollection is not. That's a very big difference that can't be solved with just running MonitorQueue in Task.Run. The code is too complicated compared to how pub/sub is done using Channels too. Just pass ChannelWriter to the asynchronous producer, ChannelReader to the asynchronous consumer. You can use ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync to pass just an IAsyncEnumerable<T> to the consumer instead of `ChannelReader

There's no reason at all for TryPeek, Task.Delay, MonitorQueue, .WaitToReadAsync() or DispatchPendingItems  with Channels either. All this code can be replaced with just await foreach(var item from reader.ReadAllAsync()). Using events is a big problem too, because .NET evens just don't understand asynchronous execution. OnItemDispatched will call the event handler in the dispatcher's thread and block if the event handler blocks. At the very least it should use BeginInvoke instead of calling the handler directly

Please try increasing preemptively the number of threads that the ThreadPool creates immediately on demand, using the SetMinThreads method: ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);, and tell us if it makes any difference.

@PanagiotisKanavos We can quibble about API design re: .NET events if you want, but since I control the entire pipeline, I'm comfortable with that choice, and am fully aware of the risks and tradeoffs. However, your suggestion to use ReadAllAsync() doesn't help me, since for whatever reason, attempting to use that method won't compile in my project (compiling to the .netstandard2.0 target, with a reference to System.Threading.Channels 8.0.0).

Please post test code so we can reproduce the problem. Mental debugging is hard. There are several things that could go wrong, eg by calling items.CompleteAdding(); only once the queue is empty means other threads could keep sending items forever. The event handler can block the monitor method.

@JimEvans it's not quibbling. The code is unusual and error prone. Yes, you can use IAsyncEnumerable if you add the Microsoft.Bcl.Async package. Again, post enough code so we can reproduce the problem instead of trying to imagine scenarios that would fail, beyond the problems the apparent but probably unrelated problems

For example, GetConsumingEnumerable can throw ObjectDisposedException if the CancellationTokenSource is disposed. The code only checks for OperationCanceledException though. Without any tracing or logging, we can't guess the sequence of events. Perhaps TestSomething exits early for some reason. monitorTask isn't awaited, so that exception is lost

Sorry, the package that adds IAsyncEnumerable to .NET Standard 2.0 is Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your insights. Simply adding that reference does not solve the compilation error. The entire project can be found at the link provided in the original question. I'm unclear what the current guidance for API design when needing an event-driven library are, especially when using async/await, but I'm always willing to learn.

suppose I wanted to replace this implementation - why? What does BlockingCollection give you that Channel doesn't do better?

If you post an actual test that reproduces the problem I can show how to simplify the channel code afterbthe fix. Right now though, the only reason I can think for the problem is premature termination of the test. No exception will be observed due to the unmonitored task

@StephenCleary Mostly this question is a thought experiment. My inclination is to continue to use Channel here. However, a collaborator on one of the potential downstream projects is very anti-dependency (please don't ask; I don't have a good understanding of why, except potentially dependency version conflicts), and compiling to .netstandard2.0 requires the addition of the System.Threading.Channels assembly as a dependency.

@JimEvans we can't run your thought experiment without the unit test that produces the problem. Nothing in the code you posted would cause the kind of blocking you describe. Other types, sure (eg, a blocking event handler, stop that never stops). We'd have to invent quirky test scenarios to cause the blocking you describe, by early termination, publishers that deadlock each other and stop publishing. Or find older versions of NUnit with concurrency issues. The test runner matters too. So does the runtime, eg back in 4.0 the max pool size was 100 only.

@JimEvans the test code can't show what's going on either. The test runner may not collect the console output, or may stop collecting it if the test ends. xUnit definitely doesn't collect it without explicit coding. Console output can't be asserted either. A far better way would be to add the output to a ConcurrentQueue and assert the number of items in the queue at the end of the test
